# Borrow checker insists on the lifetime of a dereferenced value

Tags: rust

Here's a minimal example of the issue I'm having:

```rust
struct S<'a> {
    value: &'a mut Option<()>,
}

impl<'a> S<'a> {
    fn f<'b>(&'b mut self) {
        *self.value = Some(());
        let value: &'a () = self.value.as_ref().unwrap();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f94e742d5ec95b259d41dcdbb38f884c)

Error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/lib.rs:8:34
  |
8 |         let value: &'a () = self.value.as_ref().unwrap();
  |                                        ^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined on the method body at 6:7...
 --> src/lib.rs:6:7
  |
6 |     fn f<'b>(&'b mut self) {
  |          ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:8:23
  |
8 |         let value: &'a () = self.value.as_ref().unwrap();
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
 --> src/lib.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a> S<'a> {
  |      ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:8:23
  |
8 |         let value: &'a () = self.value.as_ref().unwrap();
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The issue is that I'm expecting `f`'s `value` variable to have the lifetime `'a` as I've annotated, but the borrow checker is only content if it's `'b`. I need it to be `'a` because in my real code I derive a value from it that expects the `'a` lifetime. And it also makes sense to me that it should be `'a` because (and this is the crux of my confusion:) in `self.value` I've dereferenced `'b` away and should be left with `&'a mut Option<()>`, i.e. a value with (just) the lifetime `'a`.

I can solve it by specifying `'b: 'a` but it's actually the opposite (if anything I need `'a: 'b`); and also if `'b: 'a` then this function mutably borrows indefinitely and I can't touch the `S` after calling `f` which is a problem [<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92f2efba666b72e7743c99a02cbf8d2d).

I'm not sure if it's overconservative or if I'm actually trying to do something unsound. Looking at the lifetimes at the call-site it makes perfect sense though.

---

Some information about my real use case: what I have is a buffer of type B, and from that buffer I can derive a value of type T. T isn't just derived from B, it also has a reference to it (imagine `fn derive<'a>(self: &'a B) -> T<'a>`). T values expire and require management, so I made a manager struct M, and this is where the trouble is: M contains a mutable reference to a B and a cached T. Therefore inside M, the B reference has some lifetime, and T has it too since T refers to B. It's something like this:

```rust
struct B { ... }
struct T<'a> { ... }
struct M<'a> {
  b: &mut 'a Option<B>,
  t: T<'a>,
}
```

So as in my minimal example, I try to obtain the reference of the B (which I expected to have the lifetime of the buffer but it has the lifetime of M) so I could derive from it and then assign the result to the cached T, but I don't have the right lifetime.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d2d379013eb7d7f53438b041f736f0c ?

Comment: @PeterHall it won't work for me; `value` will have the lifetime of `'b`, and I need `'a` for the next stage in the processing. To be more specific: in the actual code there's another field in S, it also has the lifetime of `'a`, and it's derived from the `value` field. So if the `value` local has lifetime `'b` and I derive something from it, it will also have lifetime `'b`, and then I can't assign it to the field.

Comment: @MasterMastic can you include the specifics of that in your post? The borrow checker has many restrictions around mutable reference to ensure exclusivity. You're attempting to unbind the reference from `self` which is problematic since `self` could then be used to violate memory safety. There *might* be ways around it though.

Comment: @kmdreko Added more info; hope it's not too abstract. And yes, I think by dereferencing I do try to unbind it from self, could you elaborate on how it's problematic in this case?

Comment: @MasterMastic your construction sounds illegal on its face, since you'd simultaneously have a mutable and an immutable reference to something in `B`, no?

Comment: @kmdreko Oh I think you're right, I didn't realize it because of the indirection. So do you think I should use a cell here or would that not work? or is there some other pattern do you think I should employ? thanks a lot by the way, you already enlightened me.

Comment: @MasterMastic glad I could help. Not sure what you should do though without more specifics on the value you're trying to cache. My general recommendation would be to avoid references, but that goes without saying.